# Prove $(kA)^{-1}=\frac{A^{-1}}{k}$ for any scalar non zero $k$

Tags: matrices

If $A$ is $3 \times 3$ invertible matrix,
then

> show that for any scalar $k\neq 0$, $kA$ is also invertible and that
>   $$(kA)^{-1}=\frac{A^{-1}}{k}$$

Comment: To prove, just show that $$\left(\frac 1kA^{-1}\right)(kA) = I$$

Comment: how does it show that they are equal

Comment: Square matrix inverses are two-sided and unique.  Proving the result in my above comment would show that $\frac 1kA^{-1}$ has the defining property of the inverse.  Thus it is the two-sided, unique inverse.  Thus $kA$ must be invertible.

Comment: what I'm not able to understand is how does the inverse of kA leads to k coming in the denominator

Comment: @DhruvRaghunath Another way is to look this problem element-by-element.  If $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ are the elements of $A$ and $A^{-1}$, then $\Sigma_j a_{ij}b_{jl} = \delta_{il}$.  On the other hand, $ka_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}/k$ are the elements of $kA$ and $\frac1kA^{-1}$.  $\Sigma_j ka_{ij}\frac1kb_{jl} = \delta_{il}$.

Comment: @DhruvRaghunath Because you need $k\cdot \frac 1k = 1$.

Comment: thnx for the help i just realized wt @Bye_World said XD. Thanks for the help to both of u

Answer (score 3):

It is well-known that if you find an inverse for a matrix, that inverse matrix will be unique.
So what we have to do is to show that $\left(\frac 1k {A^{-1}}\right)\cdot (kA)=Id=(kA)\cdot \left(\frac 1k {A^{-1}}\right)$.

We have $\left(\frac 1k {A^{-1}}\right)\cdot (kA) = \left(\frac 1k k\right)\cdot (A^{-1}A)=1\cdot Id=Id$ and $(kA)\cdot \left(\frac 1k {A^{-1}}\right)=\left(k\frac 1k\right)\cdot (AA^{-1}) = 1\cdot Id = Id$.

So by the uniqueness of the inverse matrix we have that $\frac1k A^{-1}$ is the inverse of the matrix $kA$.